# Looking for a javascript markdown library which can parse code blocks within ``` and ```

Tags: javascript, markdown

The default markdown syntax for code blocks is "indented by 4 spaces on each line".

But this is not very convenient for long code, instead, using:

````
```
code block
```
````

will be much better.

I'm looking for a javascript markdown library has this feature, could you recommend any?

PS: I want a browser-side one.

Comment: I don't know of any parsers that do that (but there might well be!) - eitherway it shouldn't be too hard to write a simple pre-processor function that takes the triple-backtick notation and indents the code. Then you can feed it to a Markdown parser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://github.com/chjj/marked

They're referred to as "fences" and are a feature of github flavored markdown.

Comment: Thanks for recommend this, but can it run on browser side?

Comment: Yes, I use it on both the server and client on my homepage http://bbenvie.com/

Comment: Very good library, thank you!